# What data structure should i load this data into and how?

Tags: java

In the first part of my code I am reading data from a file and putting the fields into variables like this

```
Date date = rs.getDate(1);
Integer flightnumber = rs.getInt("FlightNumber");
Integer passengers = rs.getInt("Passengers");
```

so I need to put these variables into an `ArrayList` for example and then write a method that compares two variables with the ones in the list I created and returns an int being the passengers.

```
public int getPassengerNumbersFor(int flightNumber, LocalDate date)
```

The tricky part is that I cannot create any new classes and there isn't any `getFlightNumber`/ `getDate` implemented nor am I allowed to code one.  I have been told that a `HashMap` can be used but in this case I would have one key and two values which wouldn't work (`passengers` is key, `flightnumber` and `date` are values maybe).

How can I store these 3 values and then write my method?

Comment: You could use a `Pair` to hold the two values for your HashMap elements.

Comment: A map from flight numbers to maps from dates to numbers of passengers (`Map<Integer,Map<LocalDate,Integer>>`)?

Comment: Why can't you create another class?

Comment: You should definitely create a class for the Flight, grouping the three (or possibly more) individual fields. And instead of an array list i would suggest either a Map<FlightNumber, Flight>` (assuming each glith is unique, otherwise `Map<FlightNumber, List<Flight>>`) or a `TreeSet` sorted by `date`.

Comment: I would combine the date and flight number to make the keys of the `HashMap`. `2020:08:01-2345`. I would use the passenger number as the values in the `HashMap`.

Comment: Given your update, I would do what I said but with the keys and values switched.

Comment: You could have two maps, or use a container to hold the values (either a Pair, or a List for example). Also: tell your instructor that such artificial restrictions are really not a good way to design exercises. If the instructor wants to teach proper collection usage, then the example should be about collections. But here, the natural solution is to create a class that **represents** that data in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

If you were "allowed" to create classes, I would suggest an immutable class:

```java
public class Flight {

  private final LocalDate localDate;
  private final int number;
  private final List<Passenger> passengers;

  public Flight(LocalDate localDate, int number, List<Passenger> passengers) {
    this.localDate = localDate;
    this.number = number;
    this.passengers = List.copyOf(passengers);
  }

  public LocalDate getLocalDate() {
    return localDate;
  }

  public int getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public List<Passenger> getPassengers() {
    return passengers;
  }

  public int getPassengersNumber() {
    return passengers.size();
  }

  ...
}
```

Note the usage of the new [Date-Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

And then you could have another class for all the flights:

```java
public class Flights {

  private final List<Flight> flights;

  public Flights(List<Flight> flights) {
    this.flights = new ArrayList<>(flights);
  }

  public Flight getFlight(LocalDate localDate, int number) {
    return flights.stream()
            .filter(flight -> flight.getLocalDate().equals(localDate))
            .filter(flight -> flight.getNumber() == number)
            .findAny()
            .orElseThrow(InvalidFlightException::new);
  }

  public void addFlight(Flight flight) {
    flights.add(flight);
  }

  ...
}
```